# Spell checking in Spanish on LyX not working

Tags: lyx, ubuntu, spelling

The spell checking works in English, but not in any other language. In particular I am interested in Spanish. I have LyX 2.3.6.1 in Ubuntu 20.04 configured like this:

[image]

[image]

If I change "Language" to "English" in the "Document Settings" menu, the spell checking in English works flawlessly. I have tried to change the "Spellchecker engine" to the other options, but it is still the same.

## Edit

I have noticed that not only does the spellchecker not work but also the PDF is still in English. For example, it says "Figure X:" and "References" instead of "Figura X:" and "Referencias". Within LyX it is fine tough, i.e. "Figura" and "Referencias".

Comment: Strange. If you start LyX on the command line (just run the command `lyx`) and you try to use spellcheck with Spanish, does that give any output?

Comment: `apt search hunspell | grep Spanish` ... The output start with "i"  (installed) or some character ?

Comment: @Fran the output is `  Spanish dictionary for hunspell` starting with two blank spaces. I have added more information in the question.

Comment: @user171780 The important thing should be at the left of this. It should show  also   `i   hunspell-es`. Otherwise, it could be that you have not installed the Spanish dictionary.  Either way, try  with `sudo apt install  hunspell-es`. That will not hurt in any case.

Comment: @Fran thanks, that solved the spell checker issue. Post it as answer so I can accept it. I still have the issue of the PDF still being generated in English, but that may be another problem.

Comment: @user171780 Indeed there might still be another issue. Perhaps start a new question and post a minimal example LyX file (https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample) so I can see if I can reproduce. If you are extra motivated regarding this current issue, you might open an enhancement request on https://www.lyx.org/trac that LyX should at least give a user-friendly error if the required spell check library is not installed. I think that it should be feasible for LyX to detect and report that there's a problem.

Comment: @scottkosty see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616818/lyx-document-in-spanish-still-creating-pdf-in-english).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lyx need `hunspell` dictionaries to use the spellchecker. In Debian-like Linux they are provide by several packages. For the Spanish dictionary you need `hunspell-es`. You can check if it is already installed with:

```
apt search hunspell | grep Spanish
```

That should show a "i" (that mean installed), the package name, and a short description. Otherwise, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt install  hunspell-es
```

On the other hand, if you PDF show "Figure",  and so on, is another problem, surely because you have not set correctly the idiom in spite of your above screenshot. Check twice that you really selected `Spanish`. Not mandatory, but better if you select also `utf8` instead of the obsolete default (`latin9`) in "Encoding", so the Code Preview Pane (cheking complete source) must show you a start like:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
```

If your document already load `babel` and there is the `spanish` option, but you have still the problem, convert  in a  minimal example (i.e., remove all except one figure, then remove the image and reduce the caption to hello"), export it to LateX and post as a new question.