# LyX document in Spanish still creating PDF in English

Tags: lyx, languages

This is a follow up of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615990/spell-checking-in-spanish-on-lyx-not-working?noredirect=1#comment1540512_615990). I am writing a document in Spanish, I have configured it to be in Spanish:

[image]

but the PDF is still created in English:

[image]

You can see that it says "September 26, 2021" and "References" in English.

This is a MWE producing that PDF:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language spanish
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style french
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
Documento en español
\end_layout

\begin_layout Author
Juan Carlos
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Primera sección
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Un párrafo
\begin_inset space ~
\end_inset


\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand cite
key "key-1"
literal "false"

\end_inset

.
\begin_inset Float figure
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\align center
Acá iría una imagen.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Epígrafe.
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Bibliography
\begin_inset CommandInset bibitem
LatexCommand bibitem
key "key-1"

\end_inset

Referencia a un material externo.
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

I am using LyX 2.3.6.1 in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Thanks for the MWE! The PDF looks good when I compile your LyX file. Without changing anything, I get "26 de septiembre de 2021" and "Referencias". This suggests the differences are because of different TeX Lives. If you have a virtual box install of Ubuntu where you can experiment, you might consider running install-tl-ubuntu (https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu/) instead of installing Tex Live with apt. I don't recommend using that script with your main system though since it could break something. Perhaps wait for other suggestions.

Comment: I confirm that the document is fine as is, so there are some problem with your installation. In case that you are using MIkTeX on WIndows, I will start checking  if babel is already installed and updated.

Comment: Okay, I was expecting that this was some issue with my installation. I am in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I'm not sure your installation is corrupt. I think it just might be not the newest release.

Comment: Hey did you find the answer to this issue, im having the same problem with Ubuntu 22